# a function is not countably continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I and my friends confused with this statement "a function $f:X\to Y$ is not countably continuous." Does it mean that the set of discontinuities of $f$  is countable?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the definition is :

> For $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ a function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is **countably  continuous** if there is a countable cover $\{X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
>   of $X$ such that each restriction $f|X_n$ is continuous.

that you can find, e.g., [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1338515236). And this means that the set of discontinuities is countable.

Comment: Novanti: Does the definition still hold for any space $X, Y$?

Comment: Yes, I think that the definition can still hold, but I've not a reference.